# Error: Specified cast is not valid.

Tags: html, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am getting the following error. Please help me

```
    Line 90:                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Notes">
Line 91:                     <ItemTemplate>
Line 92:                         <asp:ImageButton ID="btnShowPopup" Text="Notes" Visible='<%#Eval("notesVisible")%>' runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Imgs.jpg"
Line 93:                             OnClick="Popup" />
Line 94:                     </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Where do you get the error? What type is `notesVisible`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What type is `notesVisible`? If it's not a `bool` but an `int`:

```
Visible='<%#((int)Eval("notesVisible")) == 1 ? true : false%>'
```

**Edit**: Since you have mentioned that there are nulls:

```
Visible='<%#Eval("notesVisible") == DBNull.Value ? false : Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("notesVisible"))%>
```

Comment: Hi Tim in the database the type is bit.

Comment: @user2356985: Since `bit` is also a numeric type you could try my approach. Or you need to use  a `DataAdapter` or ORM-Mapper that translates it to `bool` automatically.

Comment: Hi Tim, I used your approach. It is still showing the same error.

Comment: Could you please explain me DataAdapter or ORM-Mapper method?

Comment: @user2356985_ What is _your_ datasource?

Comment: Hi Tim, My datasource is SqlDataSource.

Comment: You could try `Convert.ToBoolean`: `Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("notesVisible")) %>'`.

Comment: Hi Tim, I tried this it says: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

Comment: FWIW, I tend to do things such as <%#true.Equals(Eval("notesVisible"))%> which works for most obvious cases and cuts down on the DBNull noise. Of course, even better would be to just not allow NULL (I'm not sure I've ever seen a bit column with a well-deserved NULL in it).

Answer (score 0):

you need to set visible property with boolean vale "true" or "false"

Eval("notesVisible") is a object not a boolean

Please use it as blow

```
Visible='<%#(Eval("notesVisible").ToString()=="somthing"?true:false)%>'
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi Pradeep, in the database the notesVisible type is bit.

Comment: bit means 0 or 1 then change it to Visible='<%#(Eval("notesVisible").toString()=="1"?true:false)%>'

Comment: Why would you change a bit to a string for comparison? And indeed why add the `?true:false` after your boolean? Isn't it a bit redundant?

Comment: Eval() method return type is Object then i need to cast it to string. Visible property accepts the boolean values so i add the ?true:false so the visible property will get proper value.

Comment: Hi it my mistake you need to write .ToString() 't' capital in place of  .toString() . I have edited my answer.

Comment: Hi Pradeep, Thank you its working but I cannot see the image in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

use visible='<%#  bool.Parse(Eval("notesVisible").ToString()) %>'